# Amazon: Wildcard MX + CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm able to only create a single record containing wildcard for MX or CNAME, but not both, it's considered a conflict. What work around is available?

Comment: It is indeed a conflict because *everything* about a cname host should be learnable from the target of the cname record. If foo.example.com cname example.com, then example.com mx also is also the *implicit* mx for foo.example.com.  Is that not what you need?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot correct, but the issue is that I'm trying to route MX at the root level to one place and route MX at the wildcard subdomain to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by:

1. Setting MX as the wildcard.
2. Setting the wildcard subdomain as an A record rather CNAME.